# How to log out using OAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I am writing the backend of my app, and use OAuth 2.0 for authentication.

I use Resource Owner Password Credentials to let my users log in. My question is, how to log out?

My guess is, just simply delete access_token and refresh_token in frontend(client), but not sure.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem .
If your app is a web app.
You should know that:
Let a user log out ,the action is control by your system, I think is nothing to do with OAuth. 
maybe you should clear the session in your application.